# Moving image below vertically centered text pushes text up

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have created a document in Word 2016. My title page is horizontally and vertically centered, with a section break (next page). I have pictures that I want to put on my title page, above and below the title. Everything works fine as long as I keep the picture(s) ABOVE the centered title and section break line. If I drag the picture below the title/section break, the text starts moving upward. I have tried every type of text wrapping and positioning option I can think of, to no avail. I don't want to have to use hard returns and page break to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing them in the Header area? They would be anchored in the header area and you would place a wrapping attribute for them to appear behind the text.